# Email with images thru PLSQL not loading properly on IOS

Tags: ios, email, plsql, utl-mail

I`ve created an email sending using PLSQL utl_mail.send.

```
utl_mail.send(sender     => 'donotreply@gmail.com',
                         recipients => 'test@gmail.com',
                         cc         => '',
                         bcc        => '',
                         mime_type  => 'text/html',
                         subject    => v_subject,
                         message    => v_message;
```

My message is in html format with Img on it like the ff.

```
1.) <img src="Link" style = "width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="Header" />
2.) <img src="Link" alt="Click Me" width="350" height="120">
```

I wonder why the first image is not loading properly when sending it to IOS Phones but the second image loads smoothly.

It loads all the images when I send it to any android phones.

Can someone help me with this weird issue i got?

Note : All images comes from same public file source.

Thanks.